Sticky column removed when going to next page of table component
I have a custom table and paginator stand alone components. When I have a table by itself sticky works fine for the column, but when I add a paginator to the table, the sticky is removed whenever I go to another page of the table or come back to the first page. I was able to solve it with this function:
ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.updateStickyColumnStyles();
}

where updateStickyColumnStyles is a function found in the angular/cdk, but this triggers change detection all the time which I really do not want. How can I solve this?

A simple way to solve this is to use NgZone method runOutsideAngular.
...
constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {}
...

...
ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
        this.updateStickyColumnStyles();
    });
}
...

If the change does not fix your issue, then the sticky requires change detection and it must happen.
